# Mixamo FBX and animation to blender

Tags: animation, armature, import, .fbx

I want to import FBX file from Mixamo into blender to render some animation but regardless of what settings I try the armature twists the model into unhuman positions. It functions proparly with the model so by reseting the rotation I can get the model with armature standing in Tpose but I cannot get any of the animations working because of the twisted position.

I also noticed that the animations are not realy animations, only frames that have the same values.

anybody running into this issue as well? or am I missing something important.

The settings

[image][image]

With Apply transforms on(actually rely gives bad results)
[image]

And the settings that I show on the pictuer only the manual orientation was different by the (laying figure) but thats not something I would be confused about...
[image]

I can un-check the use pre/post rotations but that way I achive only the same as if I reset all the bone rotations. figure in T-pose with no animation attached.

thank you everyone I am trying to figure this out for quite some time already.sorry for the lack of knowledge if Im missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

After some time and (walk outside), I got to find some sort of solution,

I used the Mixamo Collada (.dae) export that opened (after import to blender) as an armature only (no model included, Not sure why but anyway).

The difference is that the .dae file was correctly animated with no armature distortion/twists.

here is armature in the animation (sleeping position)
[image]

than I imported .fbx model in T-pose that I also run thru the Mixamo ridging process, to make the armatures matching with the (.dae).

there is some issue with the T-pose in Mixamo exports as I found in this coment on youtube (god bless him)
[image]

And then I swap the armatuers of the .fbx model
in hierarchy -> right click on armature(the one you want to !change!) ->  select 'remap User' -> in drop down menu by 'New ID' select the new armature that has the animation.

[image] 
[image]

There is some issue with the hip bone of the .dae armature but that should not be too difficult to solve.

hope I can help someone, If there is better solution how to get the mixamo Characters (animations) work good, pls post the answer ( I have tried to look countless tutorials ( most of them old by now ) and I think that things has changed and nothing of that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also,, I fixed it with a much easier solution. I downloaded the .dae file and then clicked on the arrow next to "Armature" and I clicked on the "Animation" then "Pose" then "Armature" then back to "Pose" again and it worked. Just clicking on "Pose" without going through the others doesn't work for some reason.